# installing ddd - fatal error

Tags: c++, c, ddd-debugger

So I have been trying to install DDD. I am on a Mac OS X 10.9(Mavericks) and I have the latest Xcode installed. Whenever I run my configure file the last thing I get is the following:

```
checking whether c++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether the C++ compiler (c++) compiles a simple program... no
configure: error: You must set the environment variable CXX to a working 
                  C++ compiler.  Also check the CXXFLAGS settings.
                  See the file 'config.log' for further diagnostics.
```

and whenever I check the config.log file I get:

```
configure:2684: c++ -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.C  1>&5
configure:2678:10: fatal error: 'iostream.h' file not found #include <iostream.h>
1 error generated.
configure: failed program was:
#line 2677 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"
#include <iostream.h>
int main() {
cout << "hello, world!";
; return 0; }
```

I have downloaded the gcc from sourcefourge and installed gcc-4.9 again, but I still getting the same error. Anybody knows how to fix this or what the problem maybe?

Comment: change your `<iostream.h>` to `<iostream>`

Comment: It is not HIS library, it's DDD's.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are compiling c++ program but you passing `.c` file to `c++` compiler. You passing `conftest.c` file to c++ compiler, it has to be `confest.cpp`.

`configure:2684: c++ -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.C  1>&5`

This has to be

`configure:2684: c++ -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.cpp  1>&5`

And

`fatal error: 'iostream.h' file not found #include <iostream.h>
1 error generated.`

For above error change your code

to `#included <iostream>`

instead of `#include <iostream.h>`

Comment: These are automatically generated logs. Whenever I run the configure file in order to install DDD this is what I get. So, I don't know if I can change the extension of the files or the file per se

Answer (score 0):

Just open you configure file in DDD directory and add the following

```
`<iostream>
 using namespace std;
```

`
and that should solve this error